# How to make storyboard reference part of navigation controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uistoryboard

My UI is very simple.

I have created a `UIViewController`, and embedded it into a `UINavigationController`.

Then, I put a `UIButton` on the `UIViewController`.
Then, I put a **Storyboard Reference**. And Ctrl+Drag from the button to **Storyboard Reference**, from popup selected "Show".

[image]

The problem I have is that when I run the app, when click the button, the top part of the screen view from the **Storyboard Reference** is showing behind the top bar of `UINavigationController`. Why? How to get rid of it?

Comment: Have you set up the scene in the referenced storyboard correctly?

Comment: What does "set up the scene" mean ? Could you please explain more? Thanks.

Comment: The storyboard reference needs to refer to a scene in another storyboard.  Have you set the properties of the reference to do so?

Comment: In Storyboard Reference's attribute , I have set Reference ID to another Storyboard. I can see the referenced storyboard showing after button click, the only problem is it is showing behind the navigation controller top bar. I updated my question.